# What are the advantages of using SVG animation elements?

Tags: html, svg, css-animations

There are a number of methods for animating SVG elements. The most straight forward approach is to update the properties of the SVG elements at regular intervals using JavaScript. Alternatively you can use CSS3 animations with keyframe-style property animation. There is a third option which is to use the animation properties built into SVG.

Do the animation elements in SVG provide any advantage over the alternative methods, and if so does this give cause to favour such style of animation? I'm uncertain if the sole purpose of these elements is to provide stand-alone SVG documents that are animated or if describing animations in this way yields performance benefits over alternative methods.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190684/differences-and-similarities-between-svg-and-css3-animations) which also provies a link to [this](http://justin.tv/marakana_techtv/b/284732356)