# RaphaelJS - benefits over traditional SVG and CSS3

Tags: javascript, css, svg, raphael

I'm looking to do some animations on a site and would like to use SVG graphics.

I heard about Raphael as a great library to help render graphics, but am trying to make a case at my company for why we should use it over traditional SVG or just using CSS3 animations for manipulations. From this [Stack Overflow post on SVG vs CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190684/differences-and-similarities-between-svg-and-css3-animations), this [Raphael Tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-raphael-js-library--net-7186), and [this obnoxious looking Raphael site](http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php?q=bearbones#pagetop), I've gathered a little information on why we should use Raphael library over traditional SVG or CSS3 animations:

CSS3:

- traditionally used for sprite/png animations resulting in quality loss during scaling

Traditional SVG:

- cannot manipulate existing HTML elements
- can draw things using line animations which are impossible with timing functions in CSS3
- can interact with objects AFTER you've drawn them
- SVG elements can fire events and can be scripted with SVG
- can manipulate any aspect of an imported SVG file (something like a complex logo from Illustrator)

Raphael JS:

- Seems to me to be a simple wrapper library (similar to jQuery) which makes some traditional SVG manipulation operations easier to write?

I came up with some comparisons where Raphael seems compelling...

**Shapes:**

CSS3:

```
#circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

<div id="circle"></div>
```

SVG:

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Raphael:

```
var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 500, 500);
var circle = paper.circle(100, 100, 80); //cleaner 
circle.attr({fill: 'red', stroke: 'black', 'stroke-width': 2});
```

**Manipulation:**

CSS3: something like...

```
@keyframes moveCircle {
  from { /* start value */ }
  to { /* end value */ }
}

<div id="moveCircle"></div>
```

SVG: More complicated

```
<circle id="my-circle" r="30" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange" />

  <animate 
    xlink:href="#my-circle"
    attributeName="cx"
    from="50"
    to="450" 
    dur="1s"
    begin="click"
    fill="freeze" />
```

Raphael: Something like this:

```
circle.node.onclick = function () {
    this.animate({ cx: this.cx+=100, cy: this.cy+=100}, 1000);
};
```

Moreover, it appears drawing custom lines and such with `path("M 0 0 l...")` and Bezier curves (for graphs) seems easier in Raphael, but still done with SVG and CSS3.

Basically, I don't have a compelling case because I don't fully understand CSS3 or SVG to know where Raphael comes to the rescue. I'm hoping someone can help me understand.

Answer (score 2):

Raphaels main strength comes from its backwards compatibility and being able to work with older browsers, and you haven't mentioned if this is a requirement.

If older browser support isn't a requirement, you may want to look into something like Snap or svg.js where they support extra svg elements like 'group' and can also import svg files, and then manipulate and animate. With Raphael, you have to create everything yourself, rather than use existing SVG, which can be a drawback.

Its important to realise afaik (without an extra library, and I think there is an import one out there), I don't think you can manipulate existing SVG with Raph.

Advantages of CSS3, animating can provide better performance, and I would check this especially if its likely mobile may be a significant audience. You could also look into a library like velocity.js which is good for good animation speeds.

There are also some other options, to use canvas and libraries such as fabric.js. Again it depends on browser compatibility that you need.

So basically I would try and figure out what devices and browsers you need to support first, and then there may be some trade offs alongside performance and flexibility because of this requirement.

Its also worth bearing in mind you can combine svg with css, again you may need to look into what exactly is needed in css3 and browser support.

Comment: If by "older browsers" you mean "IE 8 and lower" say that :) Note that CSS animation wasn't supported until IE10 (according to caniuse.com).

Comment: I don't think keyframes is supported in IE9 either ? This is where I hate being specific, without a specific question, as to say IE8 and lower, may imply IE9 is fine.